# Accuracy metric on imbalanced classification data

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, metrics, imbalanced-data

There has been a lot of discussion about this topic.

But I have no enough reputation i.e. 50 to comment on those posts. Hence, I am creating this one.

As far as I understand, accuracy is not an appropriate metric when the data is imbalanced.

My question is, is it still inppropriate if we have applied either the resampling method, class weights or initial bias?

 [Reference here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, it is always a good idea to test resampling techniques such as over sampling the minority class and under sampling the majority class. My advice is to start with [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/random-oversampling-and-undersampling-for-imbalanced-classification/) excellent walk through for resampling techniques using the `imblearn` package in python. Eventually, what seems to work best in most cases is intelligently combining both under and over samplers

For example, undersampling the majority class by 70% and then apply over sampling to the minority class to match the new distribution of the majority class.

To answer your question regarding accuracy: No. It should not be used. The main reason is that when you apply resampling techniques, you should never apply it on the test set. Your test set, same as in real life and in production, you never know it in advance. So the imbalance ***will always be there***.

As far as evaluation metrics, well the question you need to ask is 'how much more important is the minority class than the majority class?' how much false positives are you willing to tolerate? The best way to check for class separability is using a [ROC curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#roc-metrics). The better it looks (a nice high above the diagonal line curve) the better the model is at separating positive classes from negative classes even if it is imbalanced.

To get a single score that allows you to compare models, and if false negatives are more important than false positives (which is almost always the case in imbalanced classification), then use [F2 measure](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#precision-recall-f-measure-metrics) which gives more importance to recall (i.e. more importance to true positives detected by your model). However, the way we have always done it in my company is by examining in detail the classification report to know exactly how much recall we get for each class (so yes, we mainly aim for high recall and occasionally look at the precision which reflects the amount of false positives).

**Conclusion :**

- Always check multiple scores such as classification report, mainly recall
- If you want a single score, use F2.
- Use ROC curve to evaluate the model visually regarding class separability
- **Never** apply resampling to your test set!

Finally, it would be wise to apply a cost sensitive learning technique to your model such as class weighting during training!

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use g-mean or brier score as Prof. Harrel wrote a nice discussion on this topic. See this: https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/. Here is another one which provided a limitations of using in proper metrics. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2666827022000585